# How to retain component properties in screen rotate event?

Tags: android

I m very new to android development, i just make some simple application to practice which have "TextView" and "Button" in it. On each click the "TextSize" of TextView increase by 10. But after increasing TextSize when I rotate the screen the TextSize of TextView goes back default value.
   Anybody please tell me how to handle this, so the TextView retain its size evenafter screen rotates.

-ZKhan

Answer (score 1):

When you change the orientation then your `onCreate()` get called implicitly so to remove that 
in your `Manifest.xml` just add this in application tag `android:configChanges="orientation"`, 
this tells the system that you are going to handle orientation by your own.

Then manage your logic in *@Override onConfigurationChanged()*.

Answer (score 0):

When configuration changed your activity is destroyed and it starts again from onCreate method.So you are seeing initial size.You can use below method to save the changed size and give it back while activity is again in onCreate.You can use shared preference to store changes

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    }
```